# how to find a database that contain the list grants in the world

Tags: database, fetch, data-analysis

I'm tasked with creating a real-time visualization of grant recipients, aiming to provide transparency and insights. However, I'm facing a significant challenge due to the lack of an accessible, comprehensive database with grant recipient names.

I've diligently searched across various websites and sources but haven't found a reliable source. I'm reaching out for assistance. If you have leads, suggestions, or potential data sources, your help would be highly appreciated. How can I overcome this hurdle and find the data I need for this critical project?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some websites you might need:

[scientifyRESEARCH]: An open database of research funding opportunities.
[Open Philanthropy]: A foundation that shows its grants and reasons.
[Nature article]: An article that lists three databases of global grants and fellowships.
[GRANTS.GOV]: The official website for US federal grants.

Comment: there're no ref links attached, could you add links?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).